# Filling empty DateTime type null values based on the contiguous/corresponding non null value column SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to build a query that fills empty DateTime type null values based on the contiguous/corresponding below non-null value column, while filtering out Ids. I've looked up some answers here in stack overflow but I've not had much success. I'm not sure if this problem can be solved or addressed with just SQL or I need T-SQL (I've seen that some people take advantage of cursors but when it comes to T-SQL, I'm a newbie).

Here is my code(I'm using a CTE, but I'm aware that the same result can be achieved without a CTE).

```
WITH CTE_C AS
(
    SELECT
        c.IdHistorial, 
        CONCAT(P.PrimerNombre,' ' COLLATE MODERN_SPANISH_CI_AI,P.SegundoNombre,' 'COLLATE MODERN_SPANISH_CI_AI,P.ApellidoPaterno,' 'COLLATE MODERN_SPANISH_CI_AI,P.ApellidoMaterno) AS OCUPADA_POR,
        D.EstadoDivision,  
        CONVERT(varchar, C.FechaInicio, 20) AS Starting_Date,  
        CONVERT(varchar, C.FechaFinal, 20) AS Final_Date,
        C.Observaciones
    FROM    
        DBO.HOSPITALIZACIONCAMAS AS C
    LEFT JOIN   
        DBO.PACIENTES AS P ON C.IDPACIENTE = P.IDPACIENTE
    LEFT JOIN   
        DBO.CatalogoDivisionEstado AS D ON C.IDESTADO = D.IDESTADODIVISION
    WHERE   
        FECHAINICIO BETWEEN '2019-10-01 00:00:00.000' AND '2019-10-18 23:59:59.000'
        AND IDCAMA = '60'
)
SELECT 
    *,
    DATEDIFF(HOUR,Starting_Date,Final_Date) AS Diferencia_en_HRS
FROM    
    CTE_C
ORDER BY    
    Starting_Date
```

This is what the output looks like:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XiNqN.png)

The focus is on the Final_Date column. There are `NULL` values for some records in that column.

What I want is that the empty Final_Date column gets filled up with the contiguos-below Initial_Date column.

The desired result set should look like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIjNy.png)

I've created a much simpler table(with the same problem and no need for fancy JOINs or even CTEs) for those who want to try at [enter link description here](http://sqlfiddle.com/)

```
CREATE TABLE TEST1 
(
    ID INT NOT NULL,
    Id_Bed INT NOT NULL,
    Patients_Name varchar(50) NULL,
    Starting_Date DATE NULL,
    Final_Date DATE NULL
)

INSERT INTO TEST1 VALUES
(4883,70,'   ','2017-11-13 12:26:58','2017-11-13 12:29:53'),
(4885,70,'   ','2017-11-13 12:29:53',NULL),
(5997,70,'LAURA PATRICIA  FIGUEROA MEDRANO','2017-11-16 06:58:16',NULL),
(6268,70,'LAURA PATRICIA  FIGUEROA MEDRANO','2017-11-16 16:47:47','2017-11-16 16:48:03'),
(6269,70,'   ','2017-11-16 16:48:03','2017-11-16 16:48:05'),
(6270,70,'   ','2017-11-16 16:48:05',NULL),
(6643,60,'   ','2017-11-17 16:19:36','2017-11-17 16:19:39'),
(6644,60,'   ','2017-11-17 16:19:39',NULL),
(7379,60,'   ','2017-11-21 09:43:53','2017-11-21 09:44:59'),
(7384,60,'   ','2017-11-21 09:44:59',NULL),
(8354,70,'JHOVANA ANDREA  LOPEZ RODRIGUEZ','2017-11-23 12:40:57','2017-11-23 13:14:37'),
(8384,70,'   ','2017-11-23 13:14:37','2017-11-23 13:14:38'),
(8385,70,'   ','2017-11-23 13:14:38',NULL),
(8604,60,'   ','2017-11-24 10:37:16','2017-11-24 10:37:17'),
(8605,60,'   ','2017-11-24 10:37:17',NULL),
(7076,60,'CLAUDIA ELIZABETH PISCIL RODRIGUEZ','2017-11-19 12:53:03','2017-11-21 09:43:53'),
(7075,60,'CLAUDIA ELIZABETH PISCIL RODRIGUEZ','2017-11-19 12:53:01',NULL),
(8716,60,'   ','2017-11-24 12:16:00','2017-11-24 12:16:02'),
(8717,60,'   ','2017-11-24 12:16:02',NULL),
(6744,60,'CLAUDIA ELIZABETH PISCIL RODRIGUEZ','2017-11-17 20:42:57','2017-11-19 12:53:01'),
(8842,70,'   ','2017-11-24 17:33:01','2017-11-24 17:33:05'),
(8843,70,'   ','2017-11-24 17:33:05',NULL),
(6647,60,'CLAUDIA ELIZABETH PISCIL RODRIGUEZ','2017-11-17 16:21:04','2017-11-17 20:42:57'),
(6512,60,'ANA ADRIANA  GARCIA VILLANUEVA','2017-11-17 12:46:59','2017-11-17 16:19:36'),
(6390,60,'ANA ADRIANA  GARCIA VILLANUEVA','2017-11-17 09:50:12',NULL),
(6272,70,'JHOVANA ANDREA  LOPEZ RODRIGUEZ','2017-11-16 16:48:43',NULL),
(4907,70,'LAURA PATRICIA  FIGUEROA MEDRANO','2017-11-13 12:54:58','2017-11-16 06:58:16'),
(4886,70,'LAURA PATRICIA  FIGUEROA MEDRANO','2017-11-13 12:31:17','2017-11-13 12:54:58'),
(9331,60,'   ','2017-11-26 13:34:15','2017-11-26 13:34:20'),
(9332,60,'   ','2017-11-26 13:34:20',NULL),
(4881,70,'JEMMY  VELASCO MORA','2017-11-13 12:15:55','2017-11-13 12:26:58'),
(4755,70,'JEMMY  VELASCO MORA','2017-11-13 08:14:12',NULL),
(3995,60,'ANA ADRIANA  GARCIA VILLANUEVA','2017-11-09 10:37:03','2017-11-17 09:50:12'),
(3860,60,'ANA ADRIANA  GARCIA VILLANUEVA','2017-11-08 17:19:11','2017-11-09 10:37:03'),
(3814,70,'JEMMY  VELASCO MORA','2017-11-08 15:07:45','2017-11-13 08:14:12'),
(3788,70,'JEMMY  VELASCO MORA','2017-11-08 12:53:55','2017-11-08 15:07:45'),
(8707,60,'EMILIA  BECERRIL RAMIREZ','2017-11-24 12:04:30',NULL),
(8615,60,'EMILIA  BECERRIL RAMIREZ','2017-11-24 10:46:14','2017-11-24 12:04:30'),
(11621,70,'   ','2017-12-03 11:04:21','2017-12-03 11:04:25'),
(11622,70,'   ','2017-12-03 11:04:25',NULL)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJkvb.png)

Feel free to rewrite the query completely if necessary. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you are looking for the `LEAD()` function. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Thanks, that function solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the lead function like this:

```
select ID,ID_Bed,Patients_Name,Starting_Date,
        COALESCE(Final_date,lead(Starting_Date,1) Over(Partition by ID_Bed Order by ID)) as Final_Date 
from #TEST1
```

Comment: Thanks, It works, that was exactly what I was looking for.